# @font-face not embedding on mobile Safari (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, mobile-safari, font-face

I'm embedding fonts on a mobile website using `@font-face` (css from FontSquirrel). When I preview in desktop Safari or Chrome, the fonts embed fine, but they don't appear in mobile Safari on the iPhone/iPad. I'm not getting any errors and I can't figure out what's going wrong. Here's my CSS. Any ideas?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JottingRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/jotting_regular-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'),
         url('../fonts/jotting_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/jotting_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/jotting_regular-webfont.svg#webfonttEfFltbI') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'JottingBold';
    src: url('../fonts/jotting_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'),
         url('../fonts/jotting_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/jotting_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('../fonts/jotting_bold-webfont.svg#webfontJpUFTHYS') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I wonder that that little smiley is doing. I've seen that in a few examples.

Comment: It's probably from people copying code haha! The local is supposed to be the name of the font.. So I would put "JottingBold" instead of "☺"

Comment: The smiley is a common hack that forces the browser to not find a local copy of the font, and thus always download the web one.

Answer (score 22):

OK, I figured it out and will document for anyone who has this problem in the future. I had copied the CSS from Font Squirrel and then I had needed to redownload the actual font files later on. I didn't think that would change anything in the CSS, but it turns out that SVG fonts (which are used by mobile safari) all have an ID that is referenced in the font file and the CSS.

So, in:

```
url('../fonts/jotting_regular-webfont.svg#webfonttEfFltbI') format('svg')
```

webfonttEfFltbI is the font id. I opened the SVG font file in a text editor and found the new ID in the following line near the top of the file:

```
<font id="webfontC6xdxB57" horiz-adv-x="972" >
```

Replacing the id after the hash tag in the CSS fixed the problem.

Comment: Old post, but really helped me out!

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same situation. I resolved it by updating the paths to the font. Even though Chrome & Safari were loading them fine, iOS wasn't recognizing my path which was

```
url ('font/chunkfive/font.eot')
```

I changed that line to include a `/` to the beginning of the font path and that fixed everything.

```
url ('/font/chunkfive/font.eot')
```

You could also try using an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Font face isn't supported on MobileSafari until iOS 4.2.

Comment: That can't be true because I've had it work on mobile safari before on several occasions.

Comment: It is, check it out: http://www.zeldman.com/2010/11/26/web-type-news-iphone-and-ipad-now-support-truetype-font-embedding-this-is-huge/

Comment: That article is saying that *TRUETYPE* font support wont be available until 4.2. SVG font support has been available since 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had been working with this for a hour before realizing my stupid mistake.

Mobile Safari is CASE SENSITIVE for the fonts, while Desktop Safari is not.

If your font is titled: `font.svg`, you must add it exactly like it is. If you add it with a Capital F, Desktop Safari won't care, but mobile will.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been solved, but I had a similar problem here:

[[@font-face not working in mobile Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856308/font-face-not-working-in-mobile-webkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856308/font-face-not-working-in-mobile-webkit)

For me, all the IDs on the SVG fonts were correct; it was the FontSquirrel syntax that was wonky. Using the updated FontSpring bulletproof syntax fixed the issue for me, and seems to work entirely cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Font face does work on mobile safari, i am using on iphone 3. I also copied the code from font squirl but it didn't work. Here is the updated code. Use this and it will work everywhere.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadProBoldCondensed';
    src: url('/fonts/myriadpro-boldcond-webfont.eot#') format('eot'),
         url('/fonts/myriadpro-boldcond-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/myriadpro-boldcond-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/myriadpro-boldcond-webfont.svg#MyriadProBoldCondensed') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: @user2284570: it wasn't wrong in 2012; you may want to rephrase that a little more constructively.