# Custom webfont characters don't appear in Safari iOS 5

Tags: css, ios5, fonts, mobile-safari, font-face

[REVISED]

My custom icon font is not rendering in Mobile Safari on iOS 5. I've confirmed that the problem must be with my CSS.

The font works fine on iOS 6 and on desktop versions of Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and IE9 when using the corresponding eot and woff formats generated by http://www.fontsquirrel.com

### @font-face

I'm currently using the following simplified `@font-face` declaration (SASS):

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Boundless'
  src: asset-url('boundless.ttf', font) format('truetype')
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
```

The following HTML *works* (it renders the desired icon character in Mobile Safari on iOS 5.1:

```
<h1>&#xf0000;</h1>
```

However, I see a `<?>` glyph if I try to render it in the way that [Font-Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/sass/font-awesome.sass) does:

SASS

```
i.bicon-biology:before
  font-family: "Boundless"
  content: "\f0000"
```

HTML

```
<h1><i class="bicon-biology"></i></h1>
```

Yet Font-Awesome icons render fine on the site.

***Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?***

I should also add that I tried all the recommendations made here: [@font-face not embedding on mobile Safari (iPhone/iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412511/font-face-not-embedding-on-mobile-safari-iphone-ipad) and none worked. This includes adding the smiley-face hack, making sure my font urls are absolute, and trying svg fonts (which shouldn't be neccessary for iOS 5 anyway).

Comment: Just curious, why do you use such a far-out range of characters, rather than something you can see on the keyboard?

Comment: The range in question is deemed the "private use area" (PUA) of utf-8, so it's intended for this sort of thing. It gives me that warm and tingly feeling of doing the right thing semantically. One positive outcome is that screen readers won't try to read off the icons as characters.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. I'd been wondering about this practice for a few days. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mobile Safari apparently just doesn't like the utf-8 addresses I was using (`/0f0000`-`/0f001e`).

I edited the font to move the characters to the same positions that [Font-Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/sass/font-awesome.sass) uses (`/00f000`...), and presto, it works!

I also checked whether adding/removing `0`'s padding the left made a difference, and it works either way. There's just something about the other address range. :\

AGAIN: This is *only* an issue when the codes are used in pseudo element content. As you see above, `&#xf0000`; (and `&#x0f0000;`) rendered just fine when it was directly in the HTML.