# Iphone wont show Lucida Sans

Tags: css, font-face

[image: Font display differs]

link is :

> http://www.woolovers.com/silk-cotton/womens/sleeveless-silk-cotton-camisole.aspx

Left is iPhone display and right is PC. The fonts circled are having same css but have different display. A(pc)=B(pc) but A!=B. Any ideas?

Comment: I get a timeout trying to view the page that you linked to.

Comment: I am sorry i just asked the dev team and it is only our networks ip that can see the site.

Comment: Ok the link is live now, if you could please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jukka has said it is not a supported font on iOS so you have three options.

1. Choose a different font which is available on ALL (iOS, Android, MacOS, Windows etc.) platforms.
2. Host the font file on your web server and point to it with CSS *@font-face*.
3. Use an online font hosting service such as [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)

To point to a custom font with CSS use the code below and copy the Lucida Sans font file to your web server.

```
@font-face{
font-family: "Lucida Sans"; src:url('LucidaSans.ttf');
}
```

Note: Google Web Fonts does not have Lucida Sans available.

Comment: I have used font-face and yet only that particular font wont show. Well i guess its useless now as i asked the dev team and nobody except a person on our network can see that page. I will repost once the issue remains unsolved and is implemented on the live site.

Comment: Ok, I assume you're using the native Safari web broswer? If so it would appear it does not support @web-fonts correctly.  However there is a work around which I found here on SO.  Here's the link.  Give it a go and let me know if it works...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412511/font-face-not-embedding-on-mobile-safari-iphone-ipad

Comment: Yes the browser in iPhone itself. I already have used the bulletproof method and i tried separating the font-face (eot line) as suggested but both solutions didn't work. See this screenshot : http://i48.tinypic.com/50it6q.png. Wierdly the problem is that same css is behaving differently i.e. giving different font sizes. Let me know if you get what i am trying to say here.

Comment: Ah yes.  Mobile devices have a tendency to 'boost' font sizes.  Check out the **-webkit-text-size-adjust** CSS property.  Setting to to 100% should do the trick.  `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;`. Apple have some information about webkit-text-size-adjust on their developer page: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-text-size-adjust.

Comment: You hit the nail on its head there man! Thank you so very much. Client was getting furious! **sigh in relief**

Comment: Great! Pleased to have helped Harmeet.  Don't forget to mark this post as the correct answer (so others can benefit).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that iPhone just hasn’t got a font named Lucida Sans and therefore uses another font. Cf. to [What fonts do iPhone applications support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249251/what-fonts-do-iphone-applications-support)

Answer (score 0):

My computer doesn't show the text using `Lucisa Sans` either, because the version of the font that I have is named `Lucida Sans Unicode`. All computers doesn't have a font named `Helvetica` either.

You should use a font stack will fallbacks all the way to the default font `sans-serif` defined in CSS. That way you know that one of the fonts specified will always be used, and it won't fall back to something completely different:

```
font-family: Lucida Sans, Lucida Sans Unicode, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: I have the following css actually on the development site : font-family:Lucida Sans,Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode, lucida_sansregular. Where "lucida_sansregular" is coming through @font-face and yet it wont display lucida font only on that piece of text.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family:

> You should always include at least one generic family name in a font-family list, since there's no guarantee that any given font is available. This lets the browser select an acceptable fallback font when necessary.

I went with the following fallback fonts:

```
font-family: "Lucida Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```