# Google Fonts loading on desktop, but not on mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, fonts, google-font-api, inline-code

Per Google PageSpeed's recommendation, I inlined much of my CSS. Previously, I had minified all of my CSS through W3 Total Cache, but now I inlined much of my CSS, plus all of the CSS that controls Google Fonts.

Now Google Fonts aren't appearing on mobile devices, but they do appear on desktops. Any reason why this is the case? The mobile screen cap [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdcturano.com%2F) shows the fonts not loading.

```
<style>@font-face{font-family:'Pathway Gothic One';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Pathway Gothic One'),local(PathwayGothicOne-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pathwaygothicone/v4/Lqv9ztoTUV8Q0FmQZzPqaA6LSHyyJAN5JIFgwWnj0Az3rGVtsTkPsbDajuO5ueQw.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0100-024F,U+1E00-1EFF,U+20A0-20AB,U+20AD-20CF,U+2C60-2C7F,U+A720-A7FF}@font-face{font-family:'Pathway Gothic One';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Pathway Gothic One'),local(PathwayGothicOne-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pathwaygothicone/v4/Lqv9ztoTUV8Q0FmQZzPqaHT0-GP0evTJPrdxn7U7ioo.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0000-00FF,U+0131,U+0152-0153,U+02C6,U+02DA,U+02DC,U+2000-206F,U+2074,U+20AC,U+2212,U+2215,U+E0FF,U+EFFD,U+F000}@font-face{font-family:'Quicksand';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Quicksand Regular'),local(Quicksand-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/quicksand/v5/sKd0EMYPAh5PYCRKSryvW5Bw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0000-00FF,U+0131,U+0152-0153,U+02C6,U+02DA,U+02DC,U+2000-206F,U+2074,U+20AC,U+2212,U+2215,U+E0FF,U+EFFD,U+F000}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Condensed'),local(RobotoCondensed-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/Zd2E9abXLFGSr9G3YK2MsIPxuqWfQuZGbz5Rz4Zu1gk.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0460-052F,U+20B4,U+2DE0-2DFF,U+A640-A69F}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Condensed'),local(RobotoCondensed-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/Zd2E9abXLFGSr9G3YK2MsENRpQQ4njX3CLaCqI4awdk.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0400-045F,U+0490-0491,U+04B0-04B1,U+2116}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Condensed'),local(RobotoCondensed-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/Zd2E9abXLFGSr9G3YK2MsET2KMEyTWEzJqg9U8VS8XM.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Condensed'),local(RobotoCondensed-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/Zd2E9abXLFGSr9G3YK2MsMH5J2QbmuFthYTFOnnSRco.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0370-03FF}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Condensed'),local(RobotoCondensed-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/Zd2E9abXLFGSr9G3YK2MsDcCYxVKuOcslAgPRMZ8RJE.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0102-0103,U+1EA0-1EF1,U+20AB}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Condensed'),local(RobotoCondensed-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/Zd2E9abXLFGSr9G3YK2MsNKDSU5nPdoBdru70FiVyb0.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0100-024F,U+1E00-1EFF,U+20A0-20AB,U+20AD-20CF,U+2C60-2C7F,U+A720-A7FF}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Condensed'),local(RobotoCondensed-Regular),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/Zd2E9abXLFGSr9G3YK2MsH4vxAoi6d67T_UKWi0EoHQ.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0000-00FF,U+0131,U+0152-0153,U+02C6,U+02DA,U+02DC,U+2000-206F,U+2074,U+20AC,U+2212,U+2215,U+E0FF,U+EFFD,U+F000}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Roboto Condensed Bold'),local(RobotoCondensed-Bold),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/b9QBgL0iMZfDSpmcXcE8nBYyuMfI6pbvLqniwcbLofP2Ot9t5h1GRSTIE78Whtoh.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0460-052F,U+20B4,U+2DE0-2DFF,U+A640-A69F}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Roboto Condensed Bold'),local(RobotoCondensed-Bold),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/b9QBgL0iMZfDSpmcXcE8nIT75Viso9fCesWUO0IzDUX2Ot9t5h1GRSTIE78Whtoh.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0400-045F,U+0490-0491,U+04B0-04B1,U+2116}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Roboto Condensed Bold'),local(RobotoCondensed-Bold),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/b9QBgL0iMZfDSpmcXcE8nL8EBb1YR1F8PhofwHtObrz2Ot9t5h1GRSTIE78Whtoh.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Roboto Condensed Bold'),local(RobotoCondensed-Bold),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/b9QBgL0iMZfDSpmcXcE8nAro84VToOve-uw23YSmBS72Ot9t5h1GRSTIE78Whtoh.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0370-03FF}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Roboto Condensed Bold'),local(RobotoCondensed-Bold),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/b9QBgL0iMZfDSpmcXcE8nACS0ZgDg4kY8EFPTGlvyHP2Ot9t5h1GRSTIE78Whtoh.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0102-0103,U+1EA0-1EF1,U+20AB}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Roboto Condensed Bold'),local(RobotoCondensed-Bold),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/b9QBgL0iMZfDSpmcXcE8nGPMCwzADhgEiQ8LZ-01G1L2Ot9t5h1GRSTIE78Whtoh.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0100-024F,U+1E00-1EFF,U+20A0-20AB,U+20AD-20CF,U+2C60-2C7F,U+A720-A7FF}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto Condensed';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Roboto Condensed Bold'),local(RobotoCondensed-Bold),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v13/b9QBgL0iMZfDSpmcXcE8nPX2or14QGUHgbhSBV1Go0E.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0000-00FF,U+0131,U+0152-0153,U+02C6,U+02DA,U+02DC,U+2000-206F,U+2074,U+20AC,U+2212,U+2215,U+E0FF,U+EFFD,U+F000}</style>
```

[Can be seen here.](https://www.dcturano.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have definitions for `woff2`. This probably will not only not work on mobile but as well not in many other Desktop browsers. For example, Internet Explorer requires `eot`, Safari requires `ttf`. I think only Chrome uses `woff2`. Depending on which mobile browser you use you need a different font format. I believe Safari on IOS even uses `svg`!

I think what you did is, you opened the CSS file Google Fonts gave you and simply copied the content. The problem is, this CSS depends on the User Agent. It has different content with the correct font format for the Browser which requested.

You could use a tool like http://localfont.com to generate the correct CSS with all font formats. They have different formats for downloading fonts as well only generating CSS for inline use.

Answer (score 2):

What mobile browser are you using?

It may be because some browsers require eot/woff/otf files to load. Could you host these font files?

read about webfont and @font-face syntax here: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

also maybe a similar problem: [@font-face not embedding on mobile Safari (iPhone/iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412511/font-face-not-embedding-on-mobile-safari-iphone-ipad)