# font-family not being applied on mobile devices

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, fonts

I have a problem with the font-family property in my `css`. I have a title that I want to style using a particular font. I am using `@fontface`. On my desktop it works fine, but on `iPhone` and `iPad` I get some standard font (I think it might be times but I am not sure). I did some research and tried different formats otf ttf etc... but still wasn't working. Finally, fed up, I've tried just changing fonts on my css to other system fonts and the phone is still not recognising them. Basically it's stuck with one font. Here is a couple of examples of fonts on the desktop:

[image]

The three first images are different font-families I have applied on the desktop version. There is a system font, a google font and a custom font using `@fontface`. All work.

The fourth image is what shows both on `iPhone` and `iPad` for each one of the fonts. Always the same one. What on earth is happening? Any suggestions appreciated.

My code for the custom font is:

```
@font-face {font-family: QuaestorSans;
          src:  url("fonts/QuaestorSans-Rg.otf") format("opentype"),
                url("fonts/QuaestorSans.ttf") format("opentype");
}


.title{
  font-family: QuaestorSans;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
}
```

the html

alice soyer
                

                
                    sky on earth

There is a little animation that fades the letters in, but I wouldn't have thought that would interfere with the font-family (and only on mobile devices?).

If you want the check out the web site it's alicesoyer.com

there is only one rule for the font-family, but if you test the site on desktop and on mobile (i am testing on iPhone and iPad for now) you will see different families. Thanks

Comment: can you add some codes?

Comment: I think this will help [Font face not embedding on mobile safari iphone-ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412511/font-face-not-embedding-on-mobile-safari-iphone-ipad)

Comment: Usually you need 5 file extensions: .ogg, .woff, .wof2, .eot, .ttf; use the link from @jezE answer ;)

Comment: What about the system fonts not loading, how did you solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely caused by not having the right font format for mobile devices, try using a service like https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator to generate the correct code for the fonts you're using

Comment: hi, i know it has been a while since you have answered this question but im stuck on the same thing. I have converted my tff file to eot,woff,woff2,svg and still the font doesnt get loaded on my iphone but works on my laptop.

Comment: @kd12345 are the fonts correctly defined in your css? Are you loading them locally, or via a cdn?

Comment: i have tried both locally and via firebase storage and it seems to be working but the fonts look different in safari than on chrome (i am using Futura)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add for the answer of @Venu Madhav and @JezEmery
beside fontsquirel you can also try
[Transfonter](https://transfonter.org/)

and for the code if you are using multiple fonts on your web enclose every font in

```
@font-face {
  //font number 1 here
}
@font-face {
 // font number 2 here and so on
}
```

because I did try

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'LatoRegular';
src: url('../fonts/LatoRegular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/LatoRegular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.svg#LatoRegular') format('svg');

font-family: 'font 2';
src: url('../fonts/LatoRegular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/LatoRegular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.svg#LatoRegular') format('svg');

font-family: 'font 3';
src: url('../fonts/LatoRegular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/LatoRegular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.svg#LatoRegular') format('svg');

/* ----- so on */
}
```

to save lines of codes, yes it still worked on desktop but it failed in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Try all this formats(just example font-family)..

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'LatoRegular';
src: url('../fonts/LatoRegular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/LatoRegular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/LatoRegular.svg#LatoRegular') format('svg');
```

}

use all those formats it should work because some browsers need different formats.