# Mobile Safari Menu links and footer not displaying the font-family

Tags: html, css

Im struggling with a situation that is very strange, so the website is working fine for all browsers , but however in mobile  they don't show correct fonts for menu and footer, which both have in common is being a  tag , i don't know if it's related.

This is part of the footer :

```
 <footer>
    <div class="footer-wr">
      <div class="footer-item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="center-item">
        <a href="/privacidade" style="color:white; font-family: 'Barlow-Light';"><p class="txs"><?php menu("FOOTER_POLITICA"); ?></p></a>
        <p class="txs"><?php menu("FOOTER_COPYRIGHT"); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-item">
        <div class="center-item" id="footer_combo">
        <a href="<?php menu("FOOTER_COMBUSTIVEL_LINK"); ?>" style="color:white; font-family: 'Barlow-Light';"><p><?php menu("FOOTER_COMBUSTIVEL"); ?></p></p></a>
        <a href="<?php menu("LINK_RECLAMACOES");  ?>" style="color:white; font-family: 'Barlow-Light';"><p><?php menu("FOOTER_RECLAMACOES"); ?></p></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And this is the menu :

```
  <div class="menu_body_item">
                <li class="drd"><p class="dropb"><?php menu("MENU_GRUPO_URBANOS"); ?></p>
                <ul class="dropdownb">
                    <a href="/sobre" class="txs"><p style="font-size:20px;"><?php menu("MENU_SOBREA"); ?></p></a>
                    <a href="/compromisso" class="txs"><p style="font-size:20px;"><?php menu("MENU_COMPROMISSO"); ?></p></a>
                </ul></li>
            </div>
            <div class="menu_body_item" id="ax"><a href="/servicosempresariais"><p><?php menu("MENU_SERVICOS_EMPRESARIAIS"); ?></p></a></div>
            <div class="menu_body_item" id="ax"><a href="/servicosparticulares"><p><?php menu("MENU_SERVICOS_PARTICULARES"); ?></p></a></div>
            <div class="menu_body_item">
            <li class="drdb">    <p class="drop"><?php menu("MENU_RECURSOS_HUMANOS"); ?></p>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/trabalharnaurbanos" class="txs"><p style="font-size:20px;"><?php menu("MENU_CARREIRAS"); ?></p></a>
                    <a href="/ofertasdeemprego" class="txs"><p style="font-size:20px;"><?php menu("MENU_OFERTAS"); ?></p></a>
                </ul></li>
            </div>
            <div class="menu_body_item" id="ax"><a href="/noticias" class="txs"><p><?php menu("MENU_NOTICIAS"); ?></p></a></div>
            <div class="menu_body_item" id="ax"><a href="/contactos" class="txs"><p><?php menu("MENU_CONTACTOS"); ?></p></a></div>
```

Ive already tried to set directly the font-family into the html, ive also styled all their classes and nothing.

this is style css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Barlow-Light'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../font/Barlow-Light.ttf'),
    url('../font/barlow-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'); /*URL to font*/
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843728/font-family-not-being-applied-on-mobile-devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [font-family not being applied on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843728/font-family-not-being-applied-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: I would not post if it was related... ive checked all posts regarding this matter and not any of them fixed my issue, it is not related with web font as the font loads perfectcly on all other elements on the website